# Blender 4.0 geo nodes: Bezier curve with 5 vertices subdivide only top 2 and bottom 2

Tags: python, geometry-nodes, game-engine, geometry, units

how can i make in blender geo nodes the bezier curve only subdivide inbetween the top 2 vertices and the bottom ones, while the one vertice in the middle is unsubdivided?

Appreciate any reply

[image]

Comment: May I suggest to remove unrelated tags ? And perhaps add [bezier-curves] ?

Answer (score 0):

*(Using Blender 3.6.8)*

With *Trim Curve* nodes, the Bezier curve is split in 3 splines using the *Factor* parameter to define the endpoint positions.
**Start**: (see top branch of the following graph) The position of the second control point (i.e. with *Index* equal to 1) is recovered with a *Sample Index* node set in *Point* domain. Then the spline made of the first and second control points is subdivided once.
**End**: (see bottom branch of the following graph) The index of the before last control point is computed from the *Point Count* returned by a *Domain Size* node set in *Curve* domain, by subtracting 2 (because *Index* starts at 0). Once its position is recovered, the spline made of the before last control point and of the last control point is subdivided.
**In between both**: (see central branch of the following graph) The spline made of all control points between the second one and the before last one (included) is unmodified.

[image: GN graph]

Resources: [image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is there a method to procedurally adjust the vertex concentration along the bezier curve when extruding bezier vertices, allowing for a repetitive pattern to be visible on the curve? Additionally, is it possible to scale and shape the cubes using the point on instance node?

Comment: About the first question on extruding Bezier vertices, I would recommend to post it as an other question, as it is quite complex because a curve made by GN can not be edited as a curve afterwards. Add explicit pictures of what you would like.

Comment: About the second question, could you detail what you mean by "scaling and shaping" the cubes ? As instances, these can be rotated and scaled, but not reshaped individually. Perhaps an other post will be more suited again.